# How to count the number of repeating words in an ArrayList (without Hash)

Tags: java, arrays, search, arraylist, count

I have an `ArrayList` that the user can fill with strings by entering "1" and then entering a String while the program runs:

```
ArrayList<String> inStrings = new ArrayList<String>();

//(I left out the main while)

if (programCTRL == 1) {
    System.out.println("Enter your keyword!");
    inStrings.add(scan.nextLine());
    System.out.println(inStrings);
}
```

When the user presses 2 they should recieve the number of times a certain word repeats. The repeating strings would not have to be next to one-another. E.g. if a user types in "Bear" three times, "Owl" two times and "Cat" once, the output should be along the lines of:

```
Bear - 3.
Owl - 2.
Cat - 1.
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You could maintain a Map<String, Integer> and just update entries whenever a string is reentered.

Comment: You didn't specify if the repeating `String`s would have to be next to one another.  If they don't, you can use `Collections#frequency`.

Comment: All right I'll try the Collections method!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the same `ArrayList` without any other support structure you can sort the elements:

```
Collections.sort(inStrings, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        return s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2); // if you don't care about uppercase and lowercase;
    }
});
```

and then in a foreach loop you can count how many times each element occurs:

```
String lastElement = null;
int counter = 0;
for(String s : inStrings){
  if(lastElement == null){
    lastElement = s;
    counter = 1;
    continue;
  }
  if(!s.equals(lastElement)){
    System.out.println(lastElement + ": " + counter);
    lastElement = s;
    counter = 1;
  }
  else
    counter++;
}

if(lastElement != null)
   System.out.println(lastElement + ": " + counter);
```

Comment: One question though (and probably a noob one as well)

Comment: The comparator you use to sort the elements, is that part of the standard class library?

Comment: @VicW yes it is.. look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) If the answer solved your problem then you can accept it.

Comment: It mostly solved it, the last element is not in the output, "Cat" in the example is missing.

Comment: @VicW yeah, you're right you need to print the last element after the loop.. Try the new code

Comment: Though it also prints everything separately

Comment: `Bear: 2
Bear: 3
Bear: 3
Owl: 1
Owl: 2
Owl: 2
Cat: 1`

Comment: @VicW I think you did something wrong. This code is working as you can see [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMMG1qdEdSNEtnNEE)

Comment: All right I'll check on my end, and thanks for the help! :)